# UISearchBar does not get focus on iPad split view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uisearchbar

this is my first question on Stackoverflow. I have used SO extensively while coding an universal iOS App.

I've hit a dead end with an issue about a UISearchBar:
I have an universal app, with a tableview and a search bar. On the iPhone, the tableview is the main view controller, on the iPad, it's the masterViewController of a splitViewController.
There are different XIBs for the 2 devices, but they share the same implementation code.
The searchbar works fine, except when I first scroll down the tableview.

When I activate the searchbar with a button on the iPhone with

```
[self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

the table scrolls all the way up, the searchbar comes in view, the keyboard appears and I can start typing. Fine.

On the iPad though, where the tableview is part of the UISplitView, when I call becomeFirstResponder, the tableview does NOT scroll, the search bar does not come in view and I have no control over the search bar (nor can I click the cancel button since I don't see it). The SearchDisplayController is activated though because the tableview gets dimmed and the navigationbar moves out of view.

Can you give me any clue where to look ? I have made sure that everything is wired up in the xib ...

Cheers,
Bob

Comment: I should have mentionned that self.searchbar is an IBOutlet of the searchbar in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround that works for now, but it's a little strange that the workaround is only needed on the iPad ...
Just move the origin of the tableView's bounds to 0,0 before calling becomeFirstResponder on the searchbar. On the iPhone, this happens "automatically".

```
    CGRect newBounds = self.mainTableView.bounds;
    newBounds.origin.y = 0;
    self.mainTableView.bounds = newBounds;
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded example from http://blog.patrickcrosby.com/2010/04/27/iphone-ipad-uisearchbar-uisearchdisplaycontroller-asynchronous-example.html

Inserted string in method

```
- (void)mockSearch:(NSTimer*)timer
...

[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

It works. Hope my post helped you.

Added after TC comment: On DetailViewConroller I declared protocol:

```
@protocol SearchBarController <NSObject>
- (void) setSearchString: (NSString*) aString;
@end
```

And placed UIButton with handler:

```
- (IBAction) pressSomeButton: (id) sender
{
    [_myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
                                          inView: self.view
                        permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                        animated: YES];

    [self.searchDelegate setSearchString: @"123"];
}
```

In GenericViewController interface added SearchBarController protocol.

Implemented method of the protocol:

```
- (void) setSearchString: (NSString*) aString
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
        self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text = aString;
    });
}
```

It works file in portrait and landscape mode.

Comment: Hi, I came across this example as well.
First, I don't see what you're trying to do, since when mockSearch is called, you're actually searching and the searchbar is already the first responder since you just typed some text in it.

Second, you didn't get the point of my problem: when I call becomeFirstResponder on my searchbar, it is out of view and I can't see what I'm typing.

Thanx for trying to help, though.